# Office 365 REST Reporting Web Service errors in last hours

Tags: office365, office365api

The Exchange Reporting Service has started showing errors in the last ~24 hours for the MessageTrace report (and others).

We're getting this error:
`{"odata.error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An error occurred while processing this request."}}}`

Any way to work around this?
Any way to contact MS relevant team that can assist?

Looks like it was issue EX194594 - 
Issue went away for me on Nov 1st. around 8AM UTC.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your MIcrosoft](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 1):

I am currently experiencing the same issue and have opened premier case with microsoft.  I'm quite relieved that someone else is having the same problem.  It suggests a problem with their endpoint.  I'll let you know soon as I have an update from microsoft.

```
curl -u someuser@sometenant.onmicrosoft.com:somepasword -H "Accept: application/json" https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc/MessageTrace? -v

*   Trying 40.101.128.2...
* Connected to reports.office365.com (40.101.128.2) port 443 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 595 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: outlook.com (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: C=US,ST=Washington,L=Redmond,O=Microsoft Corporation,CN=outlook.com
*    start date: Sat, 17 Nov 2018 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: Tue, 17 Nov 2020 12:00:00 GMT
*    issuer: C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,CN=DigiCert Cloud Services CA-1
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server auth using Basic with user 'someuser@sometenant.onmicrosoft.com'
> GET /ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc/MessageTrace? HTTP/1.1
> Host: reports.office365.com
> Authorization: Basic c29tZXVzZXJAc29tZXRlbmFudC5vbm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb206c29tZXBhc3dvcmQK
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: application/json
> 
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
< Content-Length: 113
< Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< request-id: 3e07f2b3-d09c-407a-850a-d77daf7377db
< X-CalculatedBETarget: BN7PR06MB3796.namprd06.prod.outlook.com
< X-BackEndHttpStatus: 500
< X-RUM-Validated: 1
< X-MailboxGuid: bb584b32-b4ad-4220-9525-789f4f9721e8
< X-RWS-Error: System.InvalidOperationException
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< DataServiceVersion: 3.0;
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-RWS-Version: 2013-V1
< X-DiagInfo: BN7PR06MB3796
< X-BEServer: BN7PR06MB3796
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=10
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< X-Proxy-RoutingCorrectness: 1
< X-Proxy-BackendServerStatus: 500
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< X-FEServer: YTXPR0101CA0011
< Date: Tue, 29 Oct 2019 21:18:18 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host reports.office365.com left intact
{"odata.error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An error occurred while processing this request."}}}
```

Edit (from MS support):

Root cause: A recent change meant to enhance the way in which data is retrieved in the ECP is causing errors when updating report data.

Current status: We're continuing to monitor the progress of reverting the update that caused impact.